# Incompatible signatures: anyhow keep app's data?

Tags: android

With my Android application, I deployed to my phone on a computer A.

Now, in spite signing the application with the exact same certificate on computer B, it claims

> adb: failed to install MyApp-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package MyApp signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]

I can accept this as I now compiled the app on a different computer.

However I really wish to keep MyApp's data, which an uninstall by default would remove.

Is there any way to keep the app's data folder?

1. Either by *not* uninstalling it during update
2. Uninstalling it without data removal?

My phone is **not** rooted.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the signature from computer A to computer B?

Comment: "in spite signing the application with the exact same certificate on computer B" -- your error appears to be for a `debug` build, which by default uses a per-computer debug keystore. You will need to copy that keystore from Computer A to Computer B.

Comment: I copied it. And same error arrives with release build variant.